# PostgreSQL type cast to serial not working while creating a new field

Tags: sql, postgresql, casting

## Context

I would like to create a [PostgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/) [`MATERIALIZED VIEW`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/rules-materializedviews.html) with a serial created on-the-fly but the type cast to [`SERIAL`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-SERIAL) seems not to work (actually, it doesn't work even if I drop the part which creates the view and if I only take the inner `SELECT` statement on its own):

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW schema.view_m AS (
  SELECT
    1::SERIAL AS id,
    2::INTEGER as user_id 
)
```

If I replace `SERIAL` by `INTEGER` it's working, so I guess there is some reasons why it's not working with `SERIAL`.

My need is to set up this id field on-the-fly as a true id (I mean with a sequence associated to it, unique, not null, and so on):

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW schema.view_m AS (
  SELECT
    -- obviousely replace "__type__cast__goes__here__" by the right statement here:
    1::__type__cast__goes__here__ AS id, 
    2::INTEGER as user_id 
)
```

Something similar to [this](https://www.sqlmatters.com/Articles/Adding%20an%20identity%20value%20with%20Select%20Into.aspx) but for PostgreSQL.

## Question

Do you know what are the underlying technical reasons for that?

I'm using PostgreSQL 10.12.

Comment: You can't really generate a stable id "on-the-fly". When you rebuild the mview, all IDs would change as it completely deletes all rows from the mview and re-inserts new ones. It would be much better to add such a column to the table where the geometry is selected from and include that in the SELECT statement of the mview

Answer (score 1):

Use `int`.  `serial` is not really a type.  It is a way of saying that a given type (`int`) is being generated automatically.  This is apparent when you define a foreign key relationship.  The type of the foreign key needs to match the primary key, but `int` would be used to refer to `serial`.

In Postgres 10+, the solution is to avoid `serial` -- this is recommended for other reasons as well.  The new syntax makes this clearer:

```
id int primary key generated always as identity
```

The automatic generation is separate from the type name.

Comment: Great. Is there any way of creating such new field in one-shot, by the "reverse" definition `1::___ AS id` in a select statement? (it may not be possible?)

Comment: @s.k . . . I don't know exactly what you mean.  You can use a sequence, but it will be updated each time the sequence is references (well, you could read the sequence value without incrementing it).